# Normal closure of a number field and a possible quadratic field in it

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

While reading about prime decomposition in number fields, I came across following statement (stated as a fact):

> Let $K$ be a number field and $d= \text{disc}(\mathcal{O}_K)$, then the normal closure of $K$ contains $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$.

I wish to prove this but have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Definition): By definition $\sqrt{d}$ is the determinant of a matrix with entries in the normal of closure $K$.

Comment: Note, however, that ${\bf Q}(\sqrt d)$ is not always a quadratic field. It can be the case that $d$ is a square, and that the normal closure contains no quadratic field.

Comment: Yes, this in particular happens for any cubic with cyclic galois group.

Comment: I edited the title of my question. Thanks for pointing that.